# Reference Collections.Immutable in visual studio extension

Tags: c#, vsix

I have a visual studio extension (for VS 2017) that uses Roslyn in some functions and references `System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.2.0`. When I first ran it, it would complain that it didn't have a reference to the `System.Collections.Immutable` assembly, so I added it the assets in the `source.extensions.vsixmanifest` (along with `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll` and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll` as it happens).

This fixed my problem with the missing assembly, but now I get:

> Method not found: 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1 Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script.Compile(System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.

I believe it might still be referencing a different version of `System.Collections.Immutable`, while debugging the extension, if I try this:

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray))`

I get:

> error CS0433: The type 'ImmutableArray' exists in both 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Is there a way to resolve this within the extension? (things like `.config` assembly redirects don't really work well unless you edit Visual Studio's own `.config`, which I 'd prefer to avoid)